# Twig не выводит русские буквы?

Tags: twig, php

Подключил Twig на php, столкнулся с проблемой.
При выводе в шаблоне переменной

```
 {{ test }}
```

если в test строка из латинских букв, то она выводиться если из русских то нет. Как быть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался при подключении twig можно указать параметр charset

```
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array(
        'charset'=>'windows-1251',
    ));
```

По умолчанию стоит UTF-8